# jQuery - Selectively storing table data to 2d array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I came up with the problem of storing html table data to a 2D array. Instead of using nested loops, I was looking for jquery functions that would allow me to do the same. I found [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924041/store-table-in-2d-array-jquery) which seems to do the job.

```
var tRows = $('tr').map(function() {
    return [$(this).find('td').map(function() {
    return $(this).text()
    }).get()]
}).get()

console.log(tRows)
```

> **I'd like to know, how I can use a condition, in the given code, to check if the first `td` of a `tr`is empty or not (or some other condition in general) and thus not add that row to the final array.**

**EDIT:**

Reading the comments and building upon [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1816), I now have

```
var tRows = $('tr').map(function() {
  var arr = $(this).find('td').map(function() {
    return $(this).text()
  }).get();

  if (arr[0].length) return[arr]; 
}).get()
```

This works somewhat, but I was hoping to check the condition in the inner map and return a NULL instead of the entire array. From the [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260529/break-statement-in-javascript-array-map-method), it seems that it is not possible  to abort the inner map call midway, and it will return the entire array. Seems like loops might be better in the end for this job, or did I miss something?

Comment: `map()` takes parameter which gives you index of current element so you can use that and check text length like this  https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1816/

Comment: @NenadVracar Oh, I actually meant not adding the entire row i.e the array to the 2d array, instead of the cell. But I'll try to build upon the fiddle to achieve that.

Comment: `return return $(this).text() || undefined`

Comment: In that case you can do this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1817/

Comment: @NenadVracar Indeed, didn't occur to me that the inner map can be put in a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code you posted is working for you...

If you want the `.text` of the first `td` not empty of each row, the use of a combination of CSS selectors may be the solution.

[`:first-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp)
[`:not`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)
[`:empty`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp)

**EDIT**
Okay... I improved it a little.
Seem like there can ba some spaces in an empty `td`...
So I used a `regex` to test it.

Here are the new things I used:
[`:first`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:first)
[`.test()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) JavaScript method
[`.trim()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) JavaScript method

And the **CodePen** where I tryed it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.clear();
  console.log("loading...");

  var tRows = $('tr').map(function() {
    return [$(this).find('td:first').map(function() {
      var pattern = /^\s+$/;
      if($(this).text()!="" && !pattern.test($(this).text())){
        return $(this).text().trim();
      }
    }).get()]
  }).get()

  console.log(tRows)
});
```

This return: `[["blah1],[],[blah7]]`, in the CodePen...
If you do not want the empty one in the middle:

Second [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/dWXdqX?editors=1111)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.clear();
  console.log("loading...");

  var tRows = $('tr').map(function() {
    var arr = [$(this).find('td:first').map(function() {
      var pattern = /^\s+$/;
      if($(this).text()!="" && !pattern.test($(this).text())){
        return $(this).text().trim();
      }
    }).get()];

    if(arr[0]!=""){
      return arr;
    }
  }).get()

  console.log(tRows)
});
```

This return: `[["blah1],[blah7]]`

---

**2nd EDIT**
This can also be achieved this way.
*(it implies only one loop and the code is more simple to read)*.
See 3rd [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ZKOrgg?editors=1011)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.clear();
  console.log("loading...");

  var arr=[];
  var counter=0;

  $('tr').each(function() {
    var thisTDtext = [$(this).find("td").first().text().trim()];

    if(thisTDtext!=""){
      arr[counter] = thisTDtext;
      counter++;
    }
  });

  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));

});
```

This also return: `[["blah1],[blah7]]`

Comment: Throws: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: tr:first-child(td:not(:empty()))

Comment: Ok... hold on, I will try it in CodePen.

Comment: I improved it a little... Have a try!

Comment: Now if you don't want to get the empty array... I can show you.

Comment: It is similar to what I was thinking, to remove the array with empty cell, the check is performed in the outer map call, not the inner one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142362/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-anurag-daolagajao).